# Does my Java socket stay open when using it in a thread?

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader

I'm writing a simple Java server that accepts multiple client socket connections. I'm using a separate thread to handle each client/socket. Considering I have set up the networking including the `BufferedReader`, `InputStreamReader`, and `FileWriter` etc. for this client/socket.

My code is :

```
//run method of my Runnable everytime a new client connects  
public void run(){
    String message = null; 
    while((message = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
        System.out.println(message+"/n");
        //do some other things like writing this message
        //to another client or saving it in a file, etc
    }
}
```

- **Does this keep the client socket open?** or does the socket eventually makes the thread goes dead when it's done reading from the stream
- Will it keep waiting for more/new messages/data from the client socket even after it's done reading for the first time?

Answer (score 0):

Once the server accept client request, the server is capable of exchanging messages with the client endlessly until the socket is closed with its streams. 
To allow continuity in communication, you have to read from the stream inside a while loop and only exit when the client sends a termination request. So in your case the client socket is open until you read, once you exit from the loop your connection will be terminated.

Where did you create the `bufferedReader` ?

Answer (score 0):

The thread will end when the `readLine` call returns `null`.  That happens when the reader reaches the "end of stream".  If the `BufferedReader` is wrapping an input stream associated with a socket, then "end of stream" will be triggered by the socket connection closing; e.g. because the remote client / server closed it.

There is no code shown here to close the `BufferedReader`. It will be closed if either something else calls close on it, or if the `BufferedReader` object becomes unreachable.  In the latter case, the reader and the underlying socket stream and socket will *eventually* be closed when the GC finalizes the objects.

> My question is does this keep the client socket open? Or does the socket and eventually the thread goes dead when it's done reading from the stream, or will it keep waiting for more/new messages/data from the client socket even after it's done reading for the first time?

It depends.  See above.

The point is that the code as written reads until there is no more to read.  Not until "it is done".  Or to put it another way "it is done" ... if and only if the other end *tells* it so, by closing the stream.